# Destructuring Complicated Return Types

Tags: rust, odbc

Hey everyone I am pretty new to Rust and I have been banging my head against a wall for the past week trying to figure something out. I am querying a SQL database using the ODBC driver via the odbc_iter crate. I am trying to destructure what it returns. I have no clues on how to do that successfully. I have tried chopping up the elements and putting it into a struct but no luck. I have tried leaving it as is and doing me logic on that and it got really complicated really quickly. I am at the point where I would greatly appreciate an example on how to manage this situation in Rust.

Code:
'''

```
use odbc_iter::{Odbc, ValueRow, Column};
use chrono::NaiveDateTime;
fn main() {

    let key = "CONN_STR;";

    let mut connection = Odbc::connect(&key)
        .expect("failed to connect to database");

    let mut db = connection.handle();
    let query_result = db.query::<ValueRow>("EXEC dbo.BackupGet")
        .expect("failed to run query");

    for row in query_result {
        println!("{:?}", row.expect("failed to fetch row"))
    
    }
}
```

'''

Output:
'''

```
[Some(Integer(5877)), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:30:55.827)), None, Some(String("Title here")), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:31:00.313)), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:47:25.053)), Some(String("Description here")), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:31:00.730)), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:31:05.013))]

[Some(Integer(5877)), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:30:55.827)), None, Some(String("Title here")), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:31:00.313)), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:47:25.053)), Some(String("Description here")), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:31:05.400)), Some(Timestamp(2021-05-26 13:32:00.097))]
```

'''
The output has like 8 more lines of the same formatted stuff, but I omitted it so I didn't have to clean all the sensitive bits out for each one.

Comment: Does your code base have knowledge of the schema of the result set in advance (i.e. during compile time)?

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring occurs at compile time. You're dealing with results from a database, which inherently are a runtime-only construct. Specifically, each 'row' is a `Result<ValueRow, ...>`, `ValueRow` in turn is:

```rust
type ValueRow = Vec<Option<Value>>;
```

Which you cannot destructure.

The only way around this is, as you mentioned, to (validate, and) put the data in a `struct` you can then destructure.

```rust
let FetchedData { a, b, c } = FetchedData::validate(row.unwrap()).unwrap();
```

Comment: That's useful context, thank you for explaining.